# "Beleidigung", "Kränkung" oder "Affront"

Tags: word-choice

Im Wörterbuch steht:

> Kränkung: die Verletzung eines anderen Menschen in seiner Ehre
>
> Beleidigung: jede Verletzung der persönlichen Ehre eines anderen
>
> Affront: *(geh.)* verbaler oder schriftlicher Angriff bzw. Beschuldigung

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den drei Wörtern?

Comment: Intuitiv (nicht belegbar) spiegeln die Wörter die emotionale Lage der Zielperson (Kränkung -> enttäuscht; Beleidigung -> wütend; Affront -> empört) bzw. den beabsichtigten Schwerpunkt bei deren Deutung durch den Sprecher wider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wechsle dein Wörterbuch.

> Sie empfand das fehlende Geburtstagsgeschenk als große Kränkung.

Eine **Kränkung** ist etwas, was jemanden krank macht. Normalerweise kränkt man jemanden durch Unterlassen einer an sich selbstverständlichen Sache.

> Der verweigerte Handschlag zur Begrüßung wurde allgemein als Affront gewertet.

Die *Kränkung* wird zum **Affront**, wenn die Außenwirkung gemeint ist. Jemand anders hat beobachtet, wie A den B kränken will. Dafür muss B sich nichtmal gekränkt fühlen.

> Diese Ausrede war eine Beleidigung des menschlichen Verstandes.

Eine **Beleidigung** ist hingegen ein Angriff auf die Fähigkeiten eines anderen. Die Beleidigung nach der Herkunft beleidigt die (geringen) Fähigkeiten der Familie usw. gleich mit.

Comment: Die Einschränkung der Beleidigung auf Fähigkeiten kann ich nicht nachvollziehen. Dass sich jemand vielleicht nicht gekränkt/beleidigt fühlt, obwohl es so gemeint ist, ist ein interessanter Spezialfall. Affront ist aber auch nur der französische Terminus für Kränkung.

Comment: @userunknown Das ist ein bißchen zu simpel:  Im Gegensatz zu "Beleidigung" und "Kränkung" erfordert die Verwendung von "Affront" im Deutschen *Öffentlichkeit* bei der Beleidigung.

Comment: @user unknown: Wenn du einen Bauern *du Bauer* nennst, wird der die Beleidigung nicht verstehen. Nennst du ihn stattdessen *du Landei*, versteht er es, weil ihm Unkenntnis über alles nicht-ländliche vorgeworfen wird.

Comment: @Janka Natürlich *versteht* der Bauer beides. Er ist nur bei "Bauer" nicht beleidigt - er ist ja wirklich einer - und, womöglich, mit Recht stolz drauf.

Comment: @tofro: Noch eins weiter. Wenn der Bauer nicht doof ist, dann weiß er, dass "Du Bauer" vielen als eine Beleidigung gilt. Deswegen wird er die Absicht der Ehrverletzung schon als Ehrverletzung begreifen können und sich beleidigt sehen, obwohl es auf der unmittelbaren Bedeutungsebene eine wahre Tatsachenbehauptung sein könnte, die nicht anrüchig ist.

Comment: "Mein Chef rief mich in sein Büro und machte mir einen Vorschlag, den ich nur als Affront auffassen konnte." Das soll falsch sein?

Comment: Deine Deutung ist falsch.

Comment: Die Einschränkung auf Fähigkeiten ist sicher falsch.

Answer (score 3):

Objektiv handelt es sich bei einer Kränkung, einer Beleidigung oder einem Affront tatsächlich im Wesentlichen um denselben Sachverhalt. Die Wörter setzen aber unterschiedliche Akzente. Wenn der A den B beleidigt, dann ist der B vermutlich gekränkt und wird es evt. als Affront auffassen, auf den er mit einem Gegenangriff reagiert.

- Beleidigung: Der Fokus liegt meist auf dem Beleidiger A, der das Beleidigen durchführt und damit (in Deutschland) evt. gegen § 185 StGB verstößt.
- Kränkung: Der Fokus liegt praktisch immer auf dem Gekränkten B, den die Beleidigung durch A evt. körperlich krank macht, auf jeden Fall aber metaphorisch. Es geht hier also um die Befindlichkeit von B. Wenn kein Beleidiger A existiert, spricht man deshalb nicht von Beleidigung sondern z.B. von "Kränkungen der Menschheit" (Sigmund Freud).
- Affront: Der Fokus liegt auf dem skandalösen Beleidigungsakt. Das Wort ist vom Französischen *affronter*, die Stirn bieten, abgeleitet.  Wenn eine Beleidigung/Kränkung als Affront bezeichnet wird, ist der Beleidigte B in der Regel nicht machtlos. Es besteht eine erhöhte Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass B in der Lage ist, dem Beleidiger A seinerseits die Stirn zu bieten und Vergeltungsmaßnahmen zu ergreifen. Unter Umständen wird das von B sogar erwartet. Wenn er es nicht tut, ist seine Ehre verloren.

PS: Kränkungen können auch ganz ohne Beleidigungsabsicht ausgelöst werden. Sie können versehentlich erfolgen oder als Nebenwirkung von Verhalten, das völlig legal und legitim ist. (Beispiel: Wenn ein langjähriger Mitarbeiter eines Unternehmens wegen eines ernsten Fehlverhaltens zu Recht abgemahnt wird, ist das keine Beleidigung, wird ihn aber häufig sehr kränken.)

Comment: Sehe ich ähnlich, eine Kränkung kann versehentlich oder auch dann ohne Absicht erfolgen, wenn der Verursacher sie in Kauf nimmt. Beispiel: _Du stehst vor zwei Frauen, der einen machst du laufend Komplimente, die andere fühlt sich gekränkt. Sie hat das Gefühl, weniger wert zu sein._

Answer (score -1):

Ich verstehe das Wörterbuch insofern nicht, wieso der Mensch ein anderer sein muss. Wenn man selbst beleidigt/gekränkt wird, benutzt man die Wörter auch.

Ob nun "die Verletzung" oder "jede Verletzung" und der Satzbau machen natürlich keinen Unterschied. Verbal muss ein Affront auch nicht sein. Über Sepp Blatter hat mal jemand einen Koffer Spielgeld ausgeschüttet: Beleidigung, Kränkung und Affront waren beabsichtigt.

Fazit: Es gibt keinen Unterschied, außer dass Affront ein typischer Feuilletonbegriff ist.

In der Verwendung gibt es eine starke Tendenz bei Beleidigungen Absicht zu unterstellen, das ist aber nicht zwingend. Von Kränkung spricht man meist nur, wenn die Ehrverletzung Erfolg hatte. Für beides lassen Beispiele konstruieren, wo die Beteiligten sich auf Grund kultureller Unterschiede missverstehen.

A) Angenommen wir sehen beide eine Frau. Ich sage: "Schau mal, die Hure da drüben!", nicht wissend, dass es Deine Mutter ist. Es war keine Absicht Dich zu beleidigen aber es ist dennoch eine Beleidigung. In einer Machokultur müsstest Du jetzt aktiv werden.

B) Politiker S. will Politiker W. kränken und schimpft ihn einen Kommunisten. W. betrachtet sich selbst als Kommunisten und findet das erstrebenswert, weswegen er sich primär nicht gekränkt fühlt - er weiß aber dass die Aussage kränkend gemeint war, und da es eine Grenzüberschreitung ist, ist es doch eine Kränkung.

Öffentlichkeit verschärft natürlich die Wirkung von Beleidigung, Kränkung und Affront; notwendig ist sie für keines davon.

Comment: Ich kann nicht sehen, dass die Begriffe exakt deckungsgleich sind. *kränken* kann man an sich niemand, zu dem man vorher keine persönliche Beziehung hatte - Politiker *kränken* sich höchst selten, *beleidigen* können sie sich durchaus. Es gibt auch keinen rechtlichen Tatbestand der *Kränkung*, *Beleidigung* aber schon. *kränken* und *beleidigen* können  sich zwei Personen im stillen Kämmerlein, ein *Affront* erfordert aber Öffentlichkeit.

Comment: Wenn Kränkung mit Beleidigung identisch wäre, gerade dann gäbe es keinen eigenen Straftatbestand, nicht wahr? Dein "an sich" ist eine Relativierung, über die ich wohl auch nichts weiter sagen muss. Dass sich Politiker nicht kränken (gegenseitig?) - kannst Du das belegen? Für die Öffentlichkeit beim Affront hast Du auch nur die Behauptung.